# How can I say that these definitions of the general integral are equivalent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

Definition of General integral in ["Notes for First Order Partial Differential Equations" (PDF link via iitd.ac.in)](https://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Evvksrini/vvksrini/pdf/pdenotes.pdf):

> $F (u, v) = 0,$ where, $u = u(x, y, z)$ and $v =
> v(x, y, z)$ and $F$ is an arbitrary smooth function, is called a (implicit or explicit) general
> solution of $f(x,y,z,p,q)=0$ if $z, p = z_x, q = z_y$ as determined by the relation $F (u, v) = 0$ satisfy the pde $f(x,y,z,p,q)=0.$

Definition of General integral in ["Partial Differential Equations" (PDF link via nitkkr.ac.in)](https://nitkkr.ac.in/docs/11-%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations.pdf):

> If in the solution $F(x, y, z, a, b) = 0,$ we put $b = φ(a)$ and obtain the envelop of the family of surfaces $F(x, y, z, a, φ (a)) = 0,$ we had a solution containing arbitrary function $φ$. This is called the general integral.

Question:

> How can I say that these definitions are equivalent?

**My attempt:-**
In the first definition, I am having three arbitrary functions ($u = u(x, y, z)$ and $v = v(x, y, z)$ and $F$). But in the second definition, I am having only two arbitrary functions. First definition has no parameter. Second definition having a parameter $a$. I am confused with these.

Please help me.